# Can we execute Hybris integration test case directly from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring, ant, integration-testing, sap-commerce-cloud

I am able to execute test cases from hybris platform directory with 'ant alltests' command but not from eclipse.

Getting following errors while executing test cases from eclipse ->right click -> run as -> JUnit test

```
INFO  [main] (junit) [HybrisContextFactory] - Refreshing SpringContext (hybris Application context - junit) took: (29.48 s)
INFO  [main] (junit) [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing application Spring ApplicationContext for tenant junit  took: (31.27 s)
INFO  [main] (junit) [DefaultRMIRegistryService] Unexporting the registry.
de.hybris.platform.core.UninstantiableCoreApplicationContextException: Error creating Spring application context.
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:728)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:658)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:639)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:700)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:544)
    at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.setJUnitTenant(Utilities.java:1472)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.runlistener.PlatformRunListener.testRunStarted(PlatformRunListener.java:44)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.ChainingRunNotifierWrapper$1.notifyListener(ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.java:97)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.ChainingRunNotifierWrapper$SafeNotifier.run(ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.java:239)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.fireTestRunStarted(ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.java:99)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
```

Comment: I have experienced several different issues like this one when executing tests from eclipse and ended up using the hybris testweb console which you can access from `your-ip:9001/test/`. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: not able to run web module tests from testweb console.

Comment: have a look at : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/write-execute-integration-tests-hybris/

Answer (score 1):

### Yes it's possible.

Actually with an hybris 6.1 and Eclispe Neon, I was able to run Junit tests from hybris projects without any troubles from the GUI.

To make tests work from Eclispe you have to ensure that

- All your projects are properly configured in Eclipse (without errors)
- All dependencies are present in your workspace
- All configured extensions of your *localextensions.xml* file are registered at the classpath of the Eclipse JUnit test configuration.

To fix last point, perform the following steps

- Open the <kbd>Run menu</kbd>
- Open <kbd>Run Configurations</kbd> dialog box
- In the <kbd>Run Configurations</kbd> dialog box, select your test configuration
- Go to the <kbd>Classpath</kbd> tab.
- Click on <kbd>Add Projects</kbd> button.
- In the Project Selection dialog box, select all extensions you have configured in the *localextensions.xml* file.

An other tips from hybris

> If your Spring configuration does not get bootstrapped at the startup
>   of the Hybris Platform, the Spring file is probably not a part of test
>   classpath. This can either be caused by a missing project at the
>   classpath, or by not including your resources folder in the Eclipse
>   classpath at all. Assure that your .classpath file contains the
>   following line:
>   `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="resources"/>`

---

### Regarding your specific issue

It would be great to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because the issue might be relative to your specific test. Above tips can help you. Try to successfully run a test from hybris before trying your own.

---

### Resources and further readings

[Testing in SAP Hybris Commerce](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8c6e8668866910148fc390638f82bad2.html) - check **Eclipse** section

[Eclipse workspace errors - A Complete guide](https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=R5T&title=Eclipse%20workspace%20errors%20-%20A%20Complete%20guide) - contains more resources to troubleshoot errors in Eclipse

[The Hybris Testweb Frontend](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/8bec615d86691014887ca1b28c882bef.html) - if you want to test your tests from this interface, think about initializing the `junit tenant` before

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use ant from eclipse, (window > preferences > ant > runtime > ant home > and you specify where is your ant folder Eg: `C:\Program Files\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.1`)

then (window > show view > Other > select ant)

then in your ant view click on add build files (on ant icon with +) this will show you all projects in your working set (platform extention must be imported) select `platform/build.xml`.

in ant view you will see that all commands are shown, you can execute any operation from eclipse instead of command line.

Comment: Using platform/build.xml targets,we can only execute tests on all extensions or a particular extension in some cases, what if we need to execute just one test for TDD.

Comment: well, actualy you cant run a test class that requires a running tomcat because it will try to start master tenant, if your using mockito it should be ok

Comment: it is definitely possible, some of my team members do it all the time. The key is to setup your debug/runtime configuration correctly though (and I don't have it ready here sorry : ) )

Comment: did you call `Registry.activeMasterTenant()` method in your `@before` method ?